# Is `add-apt-repository` safe against a malicious network ("MITM")?

Tags: ubuntu, security, apt

When I ran it, the output was a bit suspicious:

```
# add-apt-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp85zwje4_/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp85zwje4_/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 7BB9C367 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp85zwje4_/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 7BB9C367: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ansible, Inc." imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

We're not supposed to identify keys by such short strings, since colliding keyids can be generated in [under 5 seconds](https://evil32.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about this output.

Although GPG prints the obsolete keyid, apt-add-repository is actually fetching the key using its 160 bit fingerprint.  (The fingerprint appears to be fetched over HTTPS).

https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/software-properties/main/annotate/head:/softwareproperties/ppa.py#L163

```
def verify_keyid_is_v4(signing_key_fingerprint):
    """Verify that the keyid is a v4 fingerprint with at least 160bit"""
    return len(signing_key_fingerprint) >= 160/8


class AddPPASigningKey(object):
    " thread class for adding the signing key in the background "

    GPG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS = ["gpg", "--no-default-keyring", "--no-options"]

    def __init__(self, ppa_path, keyserver=None):
        self.ppa_path = ppa_path
        self.keyserver = (keyserver if keyserver is not None
                          else DEFAULT_KEYSERVER)

    def _recv_key(self, keyring, secret_keyring, signing_key_fingerprint, keyring_dir):
        try:
            # double check that the signing key is a v4 fingerprint (160bit)
            if not verify_keyid_is_v4(signing_key_fingerprint):
                print("Error: signing key fingerprint '%s' too short" %
                    signing_key_fingerprint)
                return False
```